# Bootstrap is not working for my ASP.NET MVC (C#)

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and following along with a tutorial on ASP.NET MVC where a bootstrap.css file is downloaded from bootswatch and then placed in the Content folder of a MVC Web Application. After going to BundleConfig.cs and changing the name of the bootstrap file from bootstrap.css to bootstrap-lumen.css the new page is supposed to render flawlessly, but for some reason the navbar isn't appearing on mine.[image: My page after switching to bootstrap-lumen.css]

I've tried other css files from bootswatch like flatly:
[image: My page after switching to bootstrap-flatly.css]

In both cases the button is changing according to the new theme but the navbar just breaks and I have no idea why. I did exactly what the instructor in the tutorial did:
[image: Placing the new bootstrap files into the Content folder]

[image: Changing the bootstrap file name in BundleConfig.cs]

Here is my _Layout.cshtml file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please use text as your format for posting code. also white background images are almost offensive   as for your code, maybe there is issue in your html or maybe `site.css` overrides navbar styling

Comment: I showed the pic of the bootstrap file in my folder and the name change in BundleConfig.cs because I wanted to make it super obvious that everything that was supposed to be there was there. People might not believe you when you say you did everything the same. I don't think it's the html because I never touched it and the default theme renders the navbar without issue. As for the site.css, how do I fix that?

Comment: Fire up your developer console (F12) and see the error(s) that you are getting there.

Comment: I don't see any errors on the developer console. I even reinstalled Visual Studio 2019 but I'm getting the same thing

Comment: @BlakeOnly Where is your `lbootstrap-umen.css`  placed? Also please show your `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` code

Comment: The bootstrap-lumen.css file is in my Content folder, you can see it in the second to last image that I posted in my question. I've just added the _Layout.cshtml file at the end

Comment: @BlakeOnly Have you tried using both the bootstrap.css? Seems the nav-bar elements are not there in the bootstrap-lumen.css. Place the bootstrap-umen.css below bootstrap.css in Bundle.config and see the behavior

Comment: The problem is, that is not what the instructor did in the tutorial I'm following but I will try just in case

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I solved the problem by switching to Visual Studio 2022 and installing a few more extensions for mvc web development

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help everyone. I solved the problem by switching to Visual Studio 2022 and installing a few more extensions for mvc web development using the visual studio downloader.